# CSS selector with multiple fields and "display" property

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Given the following piece of stylesheet:

```
#cells g:hover path.arc {
  display: inherit;
}
```

what elements are precisely being selected with the syntax `#cells g:hover path.arc` and what is the effect of setting the property `display` to `inherit` ?

Comment: *What elements are precisely being selected with the syntax `#cells g:hover path.arc`?* The elements which the documentation indicates are being selected. *and what is the effect of setting the property display to inherit?* The effect which the documentation describes.

Comment: here's [an article](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/the-css-anthology-101-essential-tips-tricks-hacks-3rd-edition/online/ch01s02) explaining some CSS selectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what elements are precisely being selected with the syntax `#cells
>   g:hover path.arc`:

All child elements `path` with class `.arc` on hover in `g` elements when ancestor element has id `cells`.

> what is the effect of setting the property display to inherit

The inherit CSS-value causes the element for which it is specified to take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It is allowed on every CSS property.

The following code demonstrates the effect:

```css
#cells g:hover path.arc {
  color: inherit;
}
path.arc {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
g {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="cells">
  <g>
    <path class="arc">test</path>
  </g>
</div>
```

The text inside element `path` with class `.arc` on `:hover` inherits the color from parent element `g`. Finally worth to mention that elements [**path**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path) and [**g**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) are [**svg**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) elements.

**References**

[inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)

Comment: @Leonardo glad that I helped you :)

Comment: Not parent element, but ancestor element.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for feedback fixed.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for feedback fixed. But I refer to `g` elements that have parent element with id `cells`. So I think the parent is correct here.

Comment: Well, the selector as written means "ancestor". In the specific HTML you give, it's the parent, which is a kind of ancestor.

Comment: @torazaburo hmmm yeah I get your point. My sample html is just to demonstrates how `inherit` value applies. Is the downvote from you by the way?